# Hadoop Spark (Mapr) - AddFile how does it work

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to understand how does hadoop work. Say I have  10 directory on hdfs, it contains 100s of file which i want to process with spark.

In the book - Fast Data Processing with Spark

**This requires the file to be available on all the nodes in the cluster, which isn't much of a
problem for a local mode. When in a distributed mode, you will want to use Spark's
addFile functionality to copy the file to all the machines in your cluster.**

I am not able to understand this, will spark create copy of file on each node.
What I want is that it should read the file which is present in that directory (if that directory is present on that node)
Sorry, I am bit confused , how to handle the above scenario in spark. 
regards

Answer (score 3):

[The section you're referring to](https://books.google.com/books?id=PdqcAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT102&ots=w3nBJyv9ip&dq=This%20requires%20the%20file%20to%20be%20available%20on%20all%20the%20nodes%20in%20the%20cluster%2C%20which%20isn't%20much%20of%20a%20problem%20for%20a%20local%20mode.%20When%20in%20a%20distributed%20mode%2C%20you%20will%20want%20to%20use%20Spark's%20addFile%20functionality%20to%20copy%20the%20file%20to%20all%20the%20machines%20in%20your%20cluster&pg=PT102#v=onepage&q=This%20requires%20the%20file%20to%20be%20available%20on%20all%20the%20nodes%20in%20the%20cluster,%20which%20isn't%20much%20of%20a%20problem%20for%20a%20local%20mode.%20When%20in%20a%20distributed%20mode,%20you%20will%20want%20to%20use%20Spark's%20addFile%20functionality%20to%20copy%20the%20file%20to%20all%20the%20machines%20in%20your%20cluster&f=false) introduces `SparkContext::addFile` in a confusing context. This is a section titled "Loading data into an RDD", but it immediately diverges from that goal and introduces `SparkContext::addFile` more generally as a way to get data into Spark. Over the next few pages it introduces some actual ways to get data "into an RDD", such as `SparkContext::parallelize` and `SparkContext::textFile`. These resolve your concerns about splitting up the data among nodes rather than copying the whole of the data to all nodes.

A real production use-case for `SparkContext::addFile` is to make a configuration file available to some library that can only be configured from a file on the disk. For example, when using MaxMind's GeoIP Legacy API, you might configure the lookup object for use in a distributed map like this (as a field on some class):

```
@transient lazy val geoIp = new LookupService("GeoIP.dat", LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE | LookupService.GEOIP_CHECK_CACHE)
```

Outside your map function, you'd need to make GeoIP.dat available like this:

```
sc.addFile("/path/to/GeoIP.dat")
```

Spark will then make it available in the current working directory on all of the nodes.

So, in contrast with Daniel Darabos' answer, there are some reasons outside of experimentation to use `SparkContext::addFile`. Also, I can't find any info in the documentation that would lead one to believe that the function is not production-ready. However, I would agree that it's not what you want to use for loading the data you are trying to process unless it's for experimentation in the interactive Spark REPL, since it doesn't create an RDD.

Comment: I guess that file cannot be found if only without path provided.

Answer (score 1):

`addFile` is only for experimentation. It is not meant for production use. In production you just open a file specified by a URI understood by Hadoop. For example:

```
sc.textFile("s3n://bucket/file")
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. My question is - will this file be copied to say each node in the cluster, say if its a small file

Comment: No, if you open it with sc.textFile(), Spark will use the Hadoop file API to get the number of "splits" (pieces), and open each split as one partition. So each part of the file will be read by one machine in the cluster. If it is a small file, there will probably only be one partition.

Comment: addFile and textFile don't do the same thing and they are for different use cases.

Comment: @davideanastasia Agree. In cases in you want to run an external application, you WILL need `addFile()`. `sc.addFile("hdfs://sparkmaster:9000/programyouwanttorun.sh");`